# If $f(-f(x))=f(-f(-x))$ can we conclude that $f(x)=f(-x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $f(-f(x))=f(-f(-x)), \quad f\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$  can we conclude that $f(x)=f(-x)$?

It seems unlikely, but I'am trying to solve a functional equation where the solution seems to be $f(x)=x^2$ so it must be $f(x)=f(-x), \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

However I know that $f(-f(x))=f(-f(-x))$ but I don't know if $f$ is 1-1 so that I conclude that $-f(x)=-f(-x)$ (Frankly, if $f$ was 1-1 then it wouldn't be possible $f(x)=x^2$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f$ is injective, clearly the implication works (because $f(y)=f(z)\implies y=z$ by definition).

Yet, $f(x)=f(-x)$ is inconsistent with injectivity, so... Whoops! We just proved that $f$ cannot be injective.

So, a counterexample to your suggestion is: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x\le 0\\ x^4&\text{if }x>0\end{cases}$$

Comment: I guess $f(x)$ is the same $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ but it's ok

Comment: @user302454 Because $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$, so $f(-f(y))=0$ whatever the $y\in\Bbb R$. But clearly the function is not even.

Comment: I edited my first comment

Comment: Clear and concise.  +1

Answer (score 5):

Set $f(x)=1$ for $x\geq 0$ and $f(x)=2$ for $x<0$